# Matrix operation MPI

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I'm trying to implement a program to calculate the product and other operations without a square matrix on the cluster. I'm starting to implement an A matrix from the file (lines 3 columns 5), and then I divided this matrix into files with the use of Scatterv, but I don't receive the desired result (img output of the result).
Matrix A is structured as follows:

2 0 3 0 0

3 0 0 1 0

0 5 3 4 0

The process is running with 4 process

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

/* allocate matrix */
int malloc2ddouble(double ***array, int n, int m)
{
   double *p = (double *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
   if (!p)
   return -1;

   (*array) = (double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
   if (!(*array)) {
    free(p);
    return -1;
   }

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    (*array)[i] = &(p[i*m]);

return 0;
}

/* deallocate matrix */
double free2ddouble(double ***array)
{
   free(&((*array)[0][0]));
   free(*array);

return 0;
}

//Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int id, nproc;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);


// check file
if (argv[1]==NULL){
if(!id){
    printf("Error: insert file!\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return -1;
  }
}

MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
  printf("Error! opening file");
  exit(1);
}
// READ FILE
//if(!id){
while(ch!= EOF){
  if(ch == '\n'){
      lines++;
  }
  ch = getc(fp);
}
rewind(fp);

{
char *data[lines];
size_t n;

for(size_t i=0; i<lines; i++){
    data[i] = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    getline(&data[i], &n, fp);

    if (ferror(fp))
        perror("fopen");
}
for(size_t i=0; i<lines; i++){
    if(i<3)
            data_3[i] = strdup(data[i]);
    else if(i==3){
        for(word=strtok(data[i], " "); word; word=strtok(NULL, " ")){
            rows_A = atoi(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cols_A = atoi(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            no_zero = atoi(word);
        }

        malloc2ddouble(&A, rows_A, cols_A);
        rows_nz = malloc(no_zero*sizeof(int));
        cols_nz = malloc(no_zero*sizeof(int));

    }else{
        for(word=strtok(data[i], " "); word; word=strtok(NULL, " ")){
            rows = atoi(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cols = atoi(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            value_A = atof(word);
        }
        A[rows][cols]= value_A;

            // insert values rows and columns no-zero
        rows_nz[for_i] = rows;
            cols_nz[for_i] = cols;
        for_i++;

    }
    free(data[i]);
  }
}

fclose(fp);
//}


 /* Debug matrix A*/
 /* if(!id){
    for(int i=0; i<rows_A; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols_A; j++){
            printf("%f ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}*/

int rows_s;
int *sendcounts, *displs;
double **mParts;

sendcounts =(int*)malloc(rows_A * sizeof(int));
displs =(int*)malloc(rows_A * sizeof(int));

for(int i=0; i<nproc; i++){
    sendcounts[i] = ((i+1)*(rows_A)/(nproc)-(i)*(rows_A)/(nproc)) * rows_A;
    displs[i] = ((i)*(rows_A)/(nproc)) * rows_A;
}

rows_s = sendcounts[id]/rows_A;

malloc2ddouble(&mParts, rows_s, cols_A);

MPI_Scatterv(&A[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &mParts[0][0], sendcounts[id],MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("\nProcess: %d\n", id);
 for(int i=0; i<rows_s; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<cols_A; j++){
     printf("%f ", mParts[i][j]);
 }
  printf("\n");
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)
free2ddouble(&A);
free(rows_nz);
free(cols_nz);
MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
```

}

The output is:

Process: 0

Process: 1

2 0 3 0 0

Process: 2

0 0 0 0 0

Process: 3

0 3 0 0 0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it a [MCVE], post your command line and detail the difference between the actual and expected results.

Comment: first you should print the send counts and displacements on the root rank.